# How do I stop Image Capture from opening whenever I connect my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone

Whenever I connect my iPhone to my Mac (Lion), the Image capture app starts.

How do I stop this?

Image capture doesn't have any preferences.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Found it!

In Image Capture there's a section on the bottom-left. Make sure the iPhone is selected, otherwise the bottom settings will not appear.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use iPhoto's preferences (General tab, the "Connecting camera opens" setting).

[image]

Comment: I don't have iPhoto, this is the exact answer I've found tens of times on google, but I don't have iPhoto :(

Comment: Users don't necessarily have iPhoto installed

Comment: Every new Mac comes with iPhoto installed, and has done for several years, so by now there are very few users without iPhoto.

Comment: Not true anymore.